# Splitting pandas dataframe to feed into a scikit-learn SVC Classifier

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like

```
    a           b           c           y
0   0.004539    0.818678    194.381891  0
1   0.001367    0.243724    245.378577  0
2   1.579454    0.465842    849.943583  0
3   7.189778    0.456895    129.707932  0
4   97.743634   0.319419    120.998294  1
```

I want to split column a, b, c into features and y into labels to use them to feed into a scikit-learn SVC classifier.

I did

```
features = df[['a', 'b', 'c']]
labels = df['y']

d_train, d_test, l_train, l_test = \
        train_test_split(features, labels,
                         test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

and trained the model by doing

```
model = SVC()
model.fit(d_train, l_train)
```

but this gives me an error

`'SVC' object is not iterable`

I don't get what I am missing.

Imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

Comment: Well, you could do `labels = df.pop('y'); features = df`. Can we also see your imports please?

Comment: just added the imports. And I am still getting the same error with that answer

Comment: Okay, when I ran your code, it worked. Just restart your kernel.

Comment: I checked again. It gives me a `KeyError: 'y'` when I used pop(). any Idea?

Comment: Dont change anything in the above code. Its correct. Just try again. If still the SVC is not iterable error, then please updata the complete stack trace of error.

Comment: Well, that means you don't have `y` as a column name... :/

Comment: It may turn out to be a silly mistake from the OP's end but didn't deserve the downvote!

Comment: You might want to convert to numpy arrays.